# Run Spring Boot Headless

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and I would like to run it headless.  When I run from the terminal this is the command I'm using:

java -jar myapp.jar --spring.main.headless=true

Is this correct?  Any help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

I've faced with same problem and solved it using `SpringApplicationBuilder` class. You should set `headless` false (which is true by default). See [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#headless%28boolean%29).

My main method looks like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class);
    builder.headless(false).run(args);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `spring.main.*` properties are injected into the `SpringApplication`. It doesn't know anything about heads or headlessness. Maybe you need `java -Djava.awt.headless=true ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `SpringApplication` does support a headless mode [1], what you've got should work but is unnecessary as `true` is already the default.

[1] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L691-L998

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `headless` with a `SpringApplicationBuilder` class. Here is an example how to do it starting by command line OR deploying a war inside a Tomcat container.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(TestApp.class);

    /**
     * This method is executed when the App is loaded embedded in a Tomcat
     * @param builder
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        log.info("WAR IS STARTING..");
        builder.headless(false);
        return builder.sources(TestApp.class);
    }

    /**
     * This method is executed when the App is loaded by command line
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("JAR IS STARTING...");
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestApp.class);
        builder.headless(false);
        builder.run(args);
    }

}
```