# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException in spring boot java

Tags: java, swing, spring-boot

I  tried to run JFrameForm created by netbeans IDE using intellij, I copied source code from netbeans and paste it to new java class and create object in main function and set visible of jframe included class and run it it gives me below error

```
2019-09-21 17:36:31.363Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
INFO    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:548)
4744    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
---     at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
[       Thread-1]   at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean    at com.sunTravel.frontend.uiComponents.MainFrame.<init>    
(MainFrame.java:19)
:   at com.sunTravel.frontend.FrontendApplication.main(FrontendApplication.java:12)
Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-09-21 17:36:31.364  INFO 4744 --- [       Thread-1] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl :         
HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2019-09-21 17:36:31.367  INFO 4744 --- [       Thread-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       :     
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-09-21 17:36:31.370  INFO 4744 --- [       Thread-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : 
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My source code available below and how to resolve this?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FrontendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FrontendApplication.class, args);
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        mf.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

MainFrame class

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

 java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, 
 null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, 
 null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, 
null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, 
null,ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to disable headless property as shown [here.](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)
You will have to do it right before you create/show the JFrame.

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false"); //Disables headless
```

An example:

```
SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class, args);
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("myframe");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoApplication.class);
    builder.headless(false);
    builder.run(args);
    MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
    mf.setVisible(true);
}
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54767994/12083015) answer