# MouseInfo.getPointerInfo() does not work together with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a sproblem running my java application using the spring-boot framework.

It works without that framework without problem.

This is the code I use to detect mouse movement.

```
package com.ericsson.mj.handlers;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;

public class MouseHandler {

    private double mousePosX;
    private double mousePosY;

    public boolean detectMouseMovement() {
        try {
            PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point b = a.getLocation();
            boolean mouseMoved = false;
            double x = b.getX();
            double y = b.getY();

            if (x != mousePosX || b.getY() != mousePosY) {
                updateMousePosition(x, y);
                mouseMoved = true;
            }
            return mouseMoved;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void updateMousePosition(double x, double y) {
        mousePosX = x;
        mousePosY = y;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine like that. But onse I run the application in the Spring-Boot framework the:

```
PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
```

Fails.

> at java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo(Unknown Source)

Is the problem I get.

Why is this? Is it possible to fix, work around? I could work without spring-boot but I wanted to learn how it works so that is why I tried with it.

Comment: Is your Spring Boot application a web application, or are you somehow using Spring Boot in a Swing/AWT desktop GUI application? The mouse pointer classes you are using only work when you are using Swing or AWT, and not in a web application.

Comment: No web application. No gui yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpringBoot per default runs headless which could cause this.

See here for how to fix it [Why does Swing think it's headless under Spring Boot, but not under Spring or plain Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160353/why-does-swing-think-its-headless-under-spring-boot-but-not-under-spring-or-pl/36160652)

What happens is that SpringBoot sets `java.awt.headless` to true when starting. You can pass `-Djava.awt.headless=false` to the start parameter to disable that.

Comment: @Eisenknurr Sorry. With the edit now it appears okay though. One of the problems with "link-only answers" is that if the site were to ever be taken down then the answer is worthless.

Comment: Thanks, I will delete my comment then. :)

Comment: Thanks, after googeling how to add that to a spring application (when run in eclipse) I found the way and it worked.

Comment: @Eisenknurr Did not know about accepting answers :)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**:

By adding:

```
SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class);
builder.headless(false).run(args);
```

The application did run not headles and there after the application could be run with spring-boot.